# Is $f(x)=g(x)(\frac{1}{\sin x }-\frac{1}{ x })$ unifrmly continuous ? where $g:(0, 1)\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ be unifrmly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Let $g:(0, 1)\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ be unifrmly continuous  and $f:(0, 1)\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x)=g(x)(\frac{1}{\sin x }-\frac{1}{ x })$

I was thinking about

**1:** Is $f(x)=g(x)(\frac{1}{\sin x }-\frac{1}{ x })$ unifrmly continuous ?

**2:**  Is $f(x)=g(x)(\frac{1}{\sin x }-\frac{1}{ x })$ bounded ?

I think $f(x)$ is  unifrmly continuous

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I calculate limit in $0$ and I doubt   abut the product

Answer (score 3):

Hints: $\frac 1  {\sin x} -\frac 1  x \to 0$ as $x \to 0$. Hence this function is bounded and uniformly continuous. [A continuous function  on $(0,1)$ is uniformly continuous iff it has finite limits at $0$ and $1$].

Product of two bounded uniformly continuous functions is uniformly continuous (and bounded): Use the fact that $|f(x)g(x)-f(y)g(y)| \leq |f(x)| |g(x)-g(y)| +|g(y)| |f(x)-f(y)|$

Comment: Kavi Rama Murthy, I want to know if a function be uniformly continuous, is it bounded?

Comment: Yes, that is true for the  domain $(0,1)$ but not true for unbounded domains. @user62498

Comment: Kavi Rama Murthy, thanks for your response